# Using Kusto query to find users who have Azure global administrator role assigned

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new to Kusto Query Language and trying to write a query to find AAD accounts who have the global administrator role assigned to them and get their number of logins over a period of time (i.e., 30 days).

I thought I would find some example queries that I can start with, but I did not find any examples.

I'm not sure if my search criteria were not right, or this task may not be easily done with Kusto without utilizing additional Azure data structures.

Can you please direct me to some references that provide examples of such a query if that is possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score -2):

A good start would be the [Kusto language tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tutorial?pivots=azuredataexplorer)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm able to do the basic Kusto queries; however, I don't know how to construct a Kusto query to enumerate AAD accounts that have the global admin role. Is Kusto Query Language capable of pulling this information from AAD? Which Kusto schema element/table enables us to retrieve the sought information?